# Vue 2 - how to access computed within method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to loop through an array containing objects and grab a list of author names from these objects.

To do this I want to write a method which I will `forEach()` through. But I can't seem to access my computed property containing the array, when I `console.log(articles)` or `console.log(this.newsFeed)` it returns `undefined` or is just blank.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I don't understand what...

Here is my code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#feed',
    data: {
        newsFeed: "",
},
created: function() {
    console.log('running');
    this.getData();
    this.filterAuthors();
},
computed: 
{
    articles: function() {
        var articles = this.newsFeed.articles;
        return articles;
    },
}, 
methods: 
{
    getData: function() {
        var newsFeed = this.$http.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortby=latest&apikey='+ apikey).then(response => {
            this.newsFeed = response.body;
        }, response => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    },
    filterAuthors: function() {

        var articles = this.newsFeed.articles;
        var authorsArray = [];

        console.log(articles);

        // commented out while troubleshooting above
        // articles.forEach(function(article) {
        //  // var authors = article.author;
        //  // authorsArray.push(authors);
        //  console.log(authors);
        // });

        // return authorsArray;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: It's not `this.newsfeed.articles`, it's just `this.articles`.

Comment: Thank you - but I've tried changing to `this.articles` and the console returns `undefined`?

Comment: That's because your computed is also referring to `this.newsFeed.articles`, but `this.newsFeed` is a string. Start with `this.newsFeed` as an object that includes an `articles` member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP call you make using `this.$http` is asynchronous. Since it is asynchronous, you need to tell your code to wait till the call is finished.

In the `getData` function, you may write:

```
getData: function() {
    return this.$http.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortby=latest&apikey='+ apikey)
    .then(response => {
        this.newsFeed = response.body;
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Then write your `created` function so that the `filterAuthors` method executes after the call is finished:

```
created: function() {
    console.log('running');
    this.getData()
    .then(() => {
        this.filterAuthors();
    });
}
```

Also, the computed variable is named `articles` and therefore can be accessed via `this.articles`, not `this.newsFeed.articles`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the console is returning `undefined` when I try `this.articles`?

Comment: Just updated the answer. Thing is, you are not waiting for the call response to come through before executing the `filterAuthors` method.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I knew I was doing something stupid. I've marked this as the accepted answer :)